# NSDictionary to NSString JSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I am trying to wrap my head around pulling a keys value from a JSON array and saving it as a String for comparison later: The following code makes my app crash when it gets to this section of code. I don't understand why.

My json array looks like so:

```
[{"User_Id":"CRNA000099","User_Name":"jbliz","User_Fname":"Julia"}]
```

My xcode:

```
userarray_login = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:kNilOptions error:&error];

 NSDictionary* userType = [userarray_login objectForKey:@"User_Name"];
 NSString *userPermission = [userType objectAtIndex:0];

 if ([userPermission isEqualToString:@"jbliz"])
    {
    NSLog(@"I should get the avalue here: %@", userPermission);
}
```

I am confused between NSDictionary and NSString. Any feedback would be a

Comment: I think you app should have be crash.

Comment: It does not even compile.

Comment: My app did crash. That is why I am seeking help. :)

Comment: Edited... I guess I was not clear that my app was crashing and I know it has to do with the following code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *name=[[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[userarray_login valueForKey:@"User_Name"]]retain];
// Get the only all Names into name Array from json Array

 NSString *userPermission = [name objectAtIndex:0]; // get the first name from Array

 if ([userPermission isEqualToString:@"jbliz"])
    {
    NSLog(@"I should get the avalue here: %@", userPermission);
}
```

Comment: Try this & Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: can you explain what's changed?

Comment: Yes this did work. Thanks for updating the answer so I understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Json Array : `[{"User_Id":"CRNA000099","User_Name":"jbliz","User_Fname":"Julia"},{},...]` an array contains Dictionaries.

for this try like,

```
 NSArray * userarray_login = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    for (NSDictionary * dict in userarray_login) { 
        NSString * name = [dict objectForKey:@"User_Name"];
        if ([name isEqualToString:@"jbliz"]) {
            NSLog(@"Value is here: %@", name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json has array of Dictionary you need to follow below steps,

```
//NSJSONSerialization return you array in userarray_login 

userarray_login = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:kNilOptions error:&error];

//You fetch Dictionary from the array 
     NSDictionary* userType = [userarray_login objectAtIndex:0];

//Fetch NSString value using keyValue
     NSString *userPermission = [userType objectForKey:@"User_Name"];

//String comparison 
     if ([userPermission isEqualToString:@"jbliz"])
        {
        NSLog(@"I should get the avalue here: %@", userPermission);
    }
```

This is correct code for your stuff.